# Ajax in django.. Normal submission of form, not entering ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I have been trying this thing since three days but I didn't get what exactly my error is.. What I want is, I want the user to select options from drop-downs and click submit to view the results in a table, yeah, without page refresh.

As of now, the ajax is not being called and the form is getting submitted normally.

**Here is my JS and apply.html (JS included in the same file)**

```js
< script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"
type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filter").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/home/filter',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          mon: $('$mon').val(),
          year: $('$year').val(),
          place: $('place').val(),
        },
        x = JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function(x) {
          alert('YOHOO!');
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(x) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}

<div class="row">
  <!-- <div class="col-md-4"> -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <form action="{% url 'apply:filter' %}" method="GET" id="filter">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-right:30px;">
            <select class="form-control" id="mon" name="mon">
                            <option value="1">Jan</option>
                            ...
                            <option value="12">Dec</option>
                        </select>
          </td>
          <td style="padding-right:30px;">
            <select class="form-control" id="year" name="year">
                            <option value="2017" selected="">2017</option>
                            ...
                            
                        </select>
          </td>
          <td style="padding-right:30px;">
            <select class="form-control" id="place" name="place">
                            <option value="India" selected>India</option>
                            ...
                            
                        </select>
          </td>
          <button name="action" value="Apply Filter" class="col-lg-2" style="display: inline-block; float:right"> Apply Filter </button>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>


  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table>

        {% for emp in all_emp %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"> {{emp.emp_name}} </th>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
      <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table>
          <tr>
            {%for x in range %}
            <td></td>
            <td scope="col"> {{x}} </td>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          <tr>
            {%for d in da %}
            <td></td>
            <td scope="col"> {{d}} </td>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>



{% endblock %}
```

```
def filter(request):
mon = request.GET['mon']
year = request.GET['year']
place = request.GET['place']

all_emp= employees.objects.filter(emp_loc=place)
template = loader.get_template('apply/apply.html')

if request.GET['action'] == 'Apply Filter':

    x=monthrange(int(year), int(mon))
    d=['M', 'T', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'S', 'Su']
    da=[]
    n=x[0]
    for i in range(0,x[1]):
        da.append(d[n%7])
        n=n+1

    context = {
        "all_emp" : all_emp,
        "da" : da,
        "range":range(1,x[1]+1)

    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
    da.clear()
```

Comment: do you receive an error? If yes which one? I guess the AJAX isn't running because you don't have a CSRF cookie. There should be a error in the browser console. And do some print statements in the view. Find if something is getting though. When you want to validate a form the should be a `if form is valid` part and to achieve data via JSON do `data = request.POST` in view

Comment: as of now, I there is no error in console. and as the data is not going into ajax, all prints are working fine in view.. and where do i need to add csrf token and how?

Comment: you have a Ajax call with a if/else statement. both options have a `console.log` line so there has to be something in the console. Either you data is getting through (on `success`) and the data would be displayed or your get `error` and the error would be displayed.  `$("#filter").click(function() {` is this line triggered at any point? If yes there has to be a console.log statement.

Comment: That is what.. It seems that its not even entering into the script. no error, no console.logs nothing.. :/

Comment: ok put a `console.log` directly under the `$("#filter").click...`  if its not triggered its useless to look for other problems. Did you close everything properly? jQuery loaded? are other functions triggered on click?

Answer (score 0):

you are not changing the default behavior of the form. try doing this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filter").on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
        url: '/home/filter',
        type: 'GET',
        ...
```

use the preventDefault() method to prevent it from submitting normally.